# What would be printed?

Tags: c, printf, c-strings, strlen

Could you please explain me why the output of the following program is 1?

```
const char *str = "mms";

printf("%d\n", strlen(str + 2));

return 0;
```

If I add 1, the result is 2.

Comment: Have you learnt about pointer arithmetic yet? This seems like something that should be part of every decent C course/tutorial

Comment: Note that `strlen(str + 2)` is different from `strlen(str) + 2`. Maybe that's your source of confusion?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For starters this call

```
printf("%d\n", strlen(str + 2));
```

can invoke undefined behavior because according to the C Standard (7.21.6.1 The fprintf function)

> 9 If a conversion specification is invalid, the behavior is
> undefined.275) If any argument is not the correct type for the
> corresponding conversion specification, the behavior is undefined.

The conversion specifier `d` expects an argument of the type `int` while the expression `strlen( str + 2 )` has the type `size_t` according to the declaration of the function `strlen`

```
size_t strlen(const char *s);
```

You have to write

```
printf("%zu\n", strlen(str + 2));
        ^^^
```

You declared a pointer to a string literal

```
const char *str = "mms";
```

The string literal is internally is represented as a character array like

```
{ 'm', 'm', 's', '\0' }
```

That is it has 4 characters including the terminating zero character `'\0'`.

The pointer `str` points to the first character of the literal. The expression `str + 2` points to the third character of the literal that is to the character `'s'` due to the pointer arithmetic.

From the C Standard (7.23.6.3 The strlen function)

> 3 The strlen function returns the number of characters that precede
> the terminating null character.

So as the expression `str + 2` points  in fact to the string `"s"`  then the function will return `1` that will be outputted.

Answer (score 2):

well, `strlen` start from the pointer you pass and count until it find a NULL or `\0` character.

So `str+2` points to the letter `s` so there's just one letter before the end of the string; `str+1` points to `m` and so ... you get `2`

Answer (score 2):

The following instruction

```
 printf("%d\n", strlen(str));
```

will print `3`, because it is the length of the string `"mms"`.

Let's remember that the string pointed by `str` is stored in the following way

```
------------------
| m | m | s | \0 |
------------------
```

So `str+1` is the pointer to the second element of the string (it is equivalent to `&(str[1])`, and `str+2` to the third element (it is equivalent to `&(str[2])`,

And what is the string pointed by `str+2`? It is `"s"`. So its length is 1.

---

In case your purpose was to add `2` to the length of `str`, you have to pay attention to the use of the parenthesis:

```
printf("%d\n", strlen(str)+2);
```

In this way the argument of `strlen` is `str`, and `2` is added to the returned length.